# How do I manage $13$ people to be interacted with each other in the minimum possible time?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

I have arranged an interaction meeting of $13$ people. All I want is these $13$ people to interact with each other. As in, every person must be interacting with remaining $12$ people. How do I manage this in the minimum possible time?

Comment: How does an interaction work? Do people interact two by two in pairs? Is it a simultaneous thing, or is the interaction one-way at a time?

Comment: Yes, people interact in pairs. But,a person will only interact with one other person at a time.

Comment: Do you have in mind some kind of simultaneous pairings, which could involve up to six pairs at a time?

Comment: @hardmath , yes . If person 1 has name A ....upto 13th having M, A will be paired with L . B  - K , C - J .. in this way M will sit out for the first round. But this solution will only give me A's interaction with  the ones sitting opposite to it.

Comment: You need $\binom{13}2=13\times 6$ interactions, but only $\lfloor 13/2\rfloor=6$ interactions can take place at a time, so it will take at least $13$ rounds.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as teams playing in a tournament. It will take 13 rounds for all teams to play all possible matches, or, in your case, to perform all possible interactions. The total number of interactions is 78.

Comment: A nice diagram on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Round-robin-schedule-span-diagram.svg (Just delete the 14th player in the center. Also, I'm not sure why it says "Rotate 7 times" when it should be 13 times.)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be restated in graph-theoretical terms:

> What is the minimal number of matchings $K_{13}$ can be decomposed into?

$K_{13}$ has 78 edges and a maximum matching in it has six edges, so we need at least 13 matchings.

We can find such a decomposition. Labelling the people $0,1,\dots,12$, round 0 has the following pairings:
$$8\leftrightarrow9\tag1$$
$$10\leftrightarrow12\tag2$$
$$2\leftrightarrow5\tag3$$
$$3\leftrightarrow7\tag4$$
$$1\leftrightarrow6\tag5$$
$$4\leftrightarrow11\tag6$$
and $0$ has a "bye". Round $n$ ($0\le n\le12$) features the same pairings, only that $n$ is added to the numbers of all people and the result is taken modulo 13 (so for example $11\leftrightarrow0$ in round 1).

The bracketed numbers to the right of the pairings above are the distances between labels of the people in each pair, and they form a set of all distinct (unsigned) non-zero distances possible with 13 people involved. There are 13 of each distance in a labelled $K_{13}$, so the union of the pairings in all 13 rounds has 78 edges in total – proving that this is a decomposition of $K_{13}$ into the minimum possible number of matchings.